# An ANR issue occurred after upgrading Firebase to BoM 29.0.0

Tags: android, firebase, android-workmanager

- An ANR happened after we upgrading firebase

  - executing service [mypackage]/com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService
    com.google.android.datatransport.runtime.scheduling.jobscheduling.JobInfoSchedulerService

There's no "Stack trace" info for this ANR.
[(1) ANR_detail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCwBz.png);
[(2) ANR_devices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUb7E.png).

We cannot reproduce.

Actually, we doubted about WorkManager in the beginning. So we tried to change the version of
"androidx.work:work-runtime" from 2.5.0 to 2.7.0. However, we still got the same ANR in the Play Console.

Does anyone know what we can do to prevent the ANR?

This is our current setting:

- Firebase BoM 29.0.0

  - com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics
  - com.google.firebase:firebase-perf
  - com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing
  - com.google.firebase:firebase-dynamic-links
  - com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics
  - com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk

The old firebase version setting:

- firebaseCoreVersion = '18.0.3'
- firebasePerfVersion = '19.0.9'
- firebaseConfigVersion = '19.2.0'
- firebaseAdsVersion = '18.2.0'
- firebaseAppindexingVersion = '19.1.0'
- firebaseMessagingVersion = '20.3.0'
- firebaseDynamicLinkVersion = '19.1.0'

Comment: Its working fine lower than 29.0.0?

Comment: Current version is `29.0.2` can you use upgraded version . I recently faced an ANR in some older version of firebase upgrading fixed it . don't remember the version . Add ANR-Watchdog to get the stacktrace for ANR then only we can look for a solution.

Comment: @SagarBalyan Not sure. At least the ANR didn't exist if we set the old versions.

Comment: @ADM Thanks for your advice. We'll try 29.0.2.

Comment: Change your version then. It seems that is the problem.

Comment: @Yoki did the new version help?